# CalendarView Android Studio

Tags: java, android, user-interface, calendarview

I am trying to populate my CalendarView with events in android studio. I have already established a connection to my web service.

```
What I need my calendar to do is:

1) Turn unavailable dates another color.
2) When a date is clicked on, have some type of textview pop up with events for that particular day.
3) When an available day is clicked on, set that day to a textview.
```

I have never worked with the calendarview widget so if anyone knows where I can get answers please attach a link. Thanks.

Comment: calendarview does not have the ability to associate events with days. its just a date picker basically

Comment: so would it make sense to just create a listview to populate the dates that are received from my service layer and have the user use a date picker instead? @tyczj

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link `https://github.com/marcohc/roboto-calendar-view`. This link is the library for calendar. I already use it, work awesome.

Need add this in your gradle build file.

```
 compile 'com.github.marcohc:robotocalendarview:<release>'
```

Hope it will help you.